# How do I name a Half-Orc?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, races

I'm part of a group of new players trying out DnD 5E. One of us is creating a half-orc, and would like help choosing a name.

Of course picking a specific name is quite opinion-based, so I'm asking for resources and advice on how to choose one, not for a particular name.

**What resources might be helpful?** Are there books from other editions that might be useful? The PHB and DMG don't really get into naming a half-orc.

**What issues should we consider?** How might the parents' cultures affect the name given to their child?

**How might the half-orc's name affect our roleplaying or how the character is treated?** For instance, what if the half-orc adopts the ethnic family name of a human father and we get a character named Gorok Smith? Or what if the mother is human and decides to give the half-orc a human name with an orcish family name like Byron Karrgek? What if a human mother raised the half-orc without a father, hence she names him Byron Smith? If we keep using Byron Smith in our games, we forget that he's a half-orc.

Comment: This depends heavily on how Half-Orcs are viewed in the setting you play in. Can you share a bit about that?

Comment: We need to know what setting you're playing in, and other details of your game (edition, how are half-orcs *made*, etc).

Comment: MY friends and I are playing a DnD 5e campaign. We're still new and learning the ropes so we decided to play a published adventure "Lost Mine of Phandelver". I'm not very well-versed in the lore in the DnD world but we're pretty much "canon-ing" everything, not really deviating from the rules and lore until we get the hang of it.

Comment: Please edit this into your question.

Comment: What exactly about the statement from the PHB "Half orcs usually have names appropriate to the culture in which they were raised." doesn't answer your question?

Comment: The part where culture overrides the orcishness of the character, I guess? By the way, to all the commentors, thanks! I never even thought of these follow up questions.

Comment: Not everything has canon, so playing canon-only is going to be hard or impossible. Your DM/group *will* have to get creative regarding things like this. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I tried to edit this question to make it better match our format. I can't vote to reopen yet. Do edited questions on hold automatically enter the vote to reopen queue?

Comment: @DCShannon Yeah, editing a held question puts it into the reopen review queue (twice, I think, if the first time doesn't do anything), so we'll see what comes of that.

Comment: I see... Sorry, we're just REALLY new and I don't have much experience with open-create-your-own-world type of games. I've mulled over the comments and especially the ones about how HalfOrcs are viewed as a race and I've made a decision to have the character really confused about his name, constantly changing it to better fit in with wherever he is going. Example, when visiting a human settlement, he would hide his orcish name, Karrgek. But when he needs to sound intimidating (like in battle) he would use his Orcish name instead. Then, maybe, later on he would grow to always use his full name.